# Compute a rational limit

Tags: calculus, limits

I tried to calculate this limit using change of variable:
$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to1}\frac{\sqrt[2]{2-x} - 1}{1 + \sqrt[5]{x - 2}}$
But i don't get the result, which is -5/2.
I would appreciate if somebody can help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**: If you substitute $2-x = y^{10}$ with $y > 0$, then $\sqrt{2-x} = y^5$ and $\sqrt[5]{x-2} = -y^2$.

Your limit then becomes $\displaystyle\lim_{y \to 1}\dfrac{y^5-1}{1-y^2}$. Can you finish from here?

Comment: Sure thank you!, but how do you know what appropriate change of variable it will be useful? Any technique?

Comment: I don't like square roots or 5th roots very much, so I picked a substitution that got rid of them. By setting $2-x = y^{10}$, both the square root and the $5$-th root disappeared.

Comment: That's great! Thanks a lot.